# OAuth2 implicit grant flow from javascript avoiding refresh

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

At the moment I have a javascript client with a button doing an ajax call to a service, and I'd like to add a token-based security using OAuth. I am trying to implement an Oauth2 authorization server as well. I'm using DotNetOpenAuth and I've been checking the samples.

The issue is that I don't see how to call for a token from the javascript client without refreshing the page, because there's always a redirection. I've tried these two options, but they don't convince me:

- Open a new window from javascript (window.open) and catch the token once it is in the window.location of the popup window. That avoids the postback, but it is a bit stilted.
- Implement a service into the authorization server that returns the token via JSON. I think this could work but it wouldn't follow the Oauth2 specification, because there would be no redirection.

Is there a better option to ask for a token avoiding to refresh the whole page?

Any comment would be appreciate.
Thanks.
David

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881802/dealing-with-expired-access-tokens-in-oauth2-implicit-grant where I propose two ways to handle this issue. Not sure which one is better.