# Dealing with expired access tokens in OAuth2 implicit grant

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, single-page-application, restful-authentication

The specification of OAuth2 states that an authorization server must not issue a refresh token when using implicit grant. In our use case we protect a RESTful API with OAuth2 and use a Single Page Javascript application as a client for this API. As it would be very difficult to redirect to the authorization server after an access token has expired, we are searching for a better way to get a new valid token. I could think about two different approaches and wonder which one could be better:

1. Use a hidden iframe to Rerequest a valid access token. For this it is necessary to include a parameter like “prompt=none” which tells the OAuth provider neither to challenge authentication, nor to display an authorization page. If the user is authenticated and has authorized the application the server will send back an access token in the urls # parameters. If one of the previous conditions is not fulfilled, it will redirect with an error like #error=authentication%20lost. With this behaviour we can use short lived access tokens also with an implicit flow.
2. We could use an additional scope (e.g. offline) which tells the server to hand out a refresh token. Even if the original spec says that implicit flow does not issue refresh tokens (which is correct if the client only uses OAuth it for a first authorization) you are free to define your own scopes for your particular application. You should consider to only allow this scope from well-known clients.

Both approaches are very similar to those of OpenID Connect. Unfortunately there are not many implementations of OpenID Connect at the moment. So first step would be to extend the OAuth2 server until OIC will be more popular.

So which approach should be preferred?

**EDIT**: The token endpoint needs client authentication, which is only possible for confidential clients like server-side applications. With the second approach it would only be possible to let the RESTful API in our case the resource provider to refresh the token and send it back to the client. I think this would be a security risk. So probably we have only one valid approach.

Comment: I'm looking for the exact same thing. I can refresh the entire page, but obviously that's kinda dumb.

Comment: How do you prevent the window from being blocked by popup blockers if you go for scenario 1

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to achieve the exact same thing at the moment.

I've actually implemented **hidden iframe** approach and then realized you have to be very careful with iframes. Any malicious website can contain your iframe and get access token easily if you don't specify *X-Frame-Options*.

Best approach for *refreshing token* should be **password grant** as specified by the spec. (I wanted my users to login with their facebook account & implicit flow was easier to develop this. I have not quite figured out how to do this with password grant.)

2nd approach also came accross my mind and seems much safer than the 1st to me, since you can usually trust the *https* & *browser storage* to keep your tokens secret.

**Edit**

I realized, even with `X-Frame-Options` most browsers can't prevent redirects, because this header is attached to the response body and redirected URL will be exposed, therefore access tokens exposed.

**Update**
 Looks like hash fragment is protected by the browser when accessed from the parent page within different domain. So I assume `#access_token` is safe. My bad. Just as a reminder callback page has to store the access token in its own right, instead of (my original intention) delegating it to the parent page like `window.parent.storeAccessToken(hash);` which obviously is a dumb thing to do.

Comment: Password grant is not an option, as it would require the user to log in twice (in your example Facebook and your Javascript application). For the second approach, you would have to store the client credentials. But how would your client get them? Sure you could store them in your browser storage. But they would be also contained in your Javascript file. So everyone could read them from there. We decided to implement the hidden iframe method. But +1 for x-frame-options.

Comment: But even with x-frame-options, it cant seem to prevent redirects. Implicit flow's redirect (which will not be blocked by the browser) contains the access token attached as hash and it is easily exposed, even tough iframe is blocked I can get the access token with jquery from outside. So as long as users are logged in, attacker can get new access tokens just by making users visit some web page. I guess approval page is supposed to prevent leaking tokens to iframes.

Comment: any solution so far?

Answer (score 1):

From the [OAuth0 website](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/implicit):

> If you need to authenticate your users without a login page (for example, when the user is already logged in via SSO scenario) or get a new access_token (thus simulate refreshing an expired token), you can use Silent Authentication.

As for the [Silent Authentication](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/silent-authentication):

> However, redirecting users away from your application is usually considered disruptive and should be avoided, from a UX perspective. Silent authentication lets you perform an authentication flow where Auth0 will only reply with redirects, and never with a login page.

This will allow you to log back the user using an SSO token, without having to prompt him for credentials again.