# Where are refresh tokens generated in a JWT Authentication scheme?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, single-page-application, jwt

I'm building a SPA with AngularJS with communication to a Laravel PHP backend. The Authentication method uses JWT, with the tymon/jwt-auth PHP library, which seems to me like a great library.

When user sends his username/password, the service sends back the JWT, which is stored in localStorage on the client. This works fine. However, I want to use a refresh token to continue issuing fresh JWTs to the client, to keep the user logged in as long as he is using the application. Where are these refresh tokens supposed to be issued? Should they be issued when a user sends his username/password? If so, there doesn't seem to be a way in the tymon/jwt-auth library to send the refresh token to the client. Please help, I'm having a lot of trouble conceptualizing how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you get issued a refresh token when you authenticate with an [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) authorization server depends on which [OAuth grant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31768524/18044) you're using.

When your client is a SPA (an untrusted client), you're probably using the implicit grant and that grant does not support refresh tokens.

Some companies have implemented libraries that are able to refresh access tokens issued by the authorization server using requests in a hidden `IFRAME`. I'm not familiar with the library you are using.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24881802/18044) for more info.